# How to modify svg path element positioning?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, svg

I have a problem with svg path element. I am working on an application in which we can convert an svg document from html document. But i am stuck in how to position the path element correctly. The path element is :

```
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path649-3"
     d="m 5159.0706,-976.95064 c -4.7204,-0.3596 -8.7292,0.4102 -12.125,1.4063 -4.182,1.2266 -7.775,2.8656 -10.0625,6.3125 -1.0568,1.5913 -2.1471,3.8178 -2.0313,6.2812 0.1986,4.2925 2.7407,6.607 5.25,8.5625 1.3363,1.0437 2.8781,1.733 4.5313,2.3438 1.6607,0.609 3.4583,1.1908 5.5,1.3125 6.7228,0.4069 12.4914,-1.874 15.7187,-5.5313 1.1464,-1.2969 2.1272,-3.1072 2.1563,-5.25 0.03,-2.2608 -1.0388,-3.9544 -2.4063,-5.2812 -2.0466,-1.9869 -5.0407,-3.3151 -8.8125,-3.5625 -4.5619,-0.2975 -8.8943,1.5695 -10.7187,4.1562 -0.7285,1.0329 -1.1842,2.7273 -0.75,4.2813 0.3529,1.2641 1.3731,2.3243 2.6875,3.0312 1.3144,0.707 2.9197,1.0523 4.5625,0.875 0.2288,-0.024 0.5203,-0.03 0.8125,-0.125 0.2921,-0.095 0.588,-0.2853 0.7812,-0.625 l 0.25,-0.4687 -0.4375,-0.25 c -0.4511,-0.2397 -0.9112,-0.1551 -1.3125,-0.094 -0.4013,0.061 -0.7811,0.1311 -1.0312,0.125 -1.3586,-0.033 -2.7476,-0.471 -3.6875,-1.25 -0.9399,-0.779 -1.478,-1.8608 -1.2188,-3.4063 0.1524,-0.8985 1.0113,-1.8397 1.7188,-2.4062 2.3013,-1.8447 5.6434,-2.5256 8.8437,-2.2188 3.2003,0.3069 6.2281,1.6132 7.875,3.5938 0.6165,0.742 1.2521,2.1606 1.3125,3.1875 0.109,1.9047 -0.7013,3.3083 -1.625,4.4375 -0.7621,0.9324 -1.5482,1.5761 -2.5,2.1562 -1.8485,1.1256 -4.4084,2.2787 -7.0625,2.5 -4.7614,0.396 -9.6079,-0.4293 -12.9062,-2.0625 -3.183,-1.5764 -6.165,-4.3626 -6,-8.7187 0.1603,-4.2426 2.7614,-6.4525 5.7187,-8.2813 3.2571,-2.0139 7.4089,-2.9623 12.0625,-3.2812 5.0629,-0.345 9.571,0.9291 12.8438,2.3125 1.7146,0.725 3.2854,1.7907 4.5625,2.9375 2.5672,2.3035 5.0625,5.4942 5.0625,9.875 9e-4,3.3952 -1.2308,5.9497 -3.0625,8 -1.8318,2.0503 -4.2832,3.5748 -6.6563,4.7187 -3.4175,1.6511 -7.8129,2.6884 -12.3437,2.8125 -4.7182,0.1323 -9.6323,-0.5946 -13.75,-1.5625 -3.8269,-0.8997 -7.945,-2.3133 -11.75,-3.625 -3.6367,-1.2503 -6.898,-2.5018 -10.75,-4.0312 0.602,-1.1329 1.4279,-2.1479 1.625,-3.7813 0.3241,-2.6722 -0.6551,-4.8003 -1.6875,-6.25 -3.1762,-4.4641 -9.9683,-6.7451 -17.125,-6.0937 -0.7652,0.069 -1.6636,0.2782 -2.4688,0.4375 -0.428,0.084 -0.8889,0.2421 -1.3125,0.3437 -0.4236,0.1017 -0.8315,0.142 -0.9375,0.125 0.1227,0.02 -0.096,-0.059 -0.2812,-0.1875 -0.1851,-0.1288 -0.4111,-0.2944 -0.5625,-0.4062 -2.4744,-1.8396 -5.6892,-3.1674 -9.75,-3.2813 -3.7067,-0.1036 -7.1873,1.2376 -9.75,3.0625 -2.4846,1.7653 -4.7137,4.4527 -5.0625,8 -0.1632,1.653 0.1654,2.9444 0.4062,4.375 -2.4116,1.2226 -5.0787,2.5372 -7.9687,3.75 -2.9192,1.2199 -6.0289,2.5356 -9.25,2.8438 -2.8351,0.2712 -5.0866,-0.2115 -6.5938,-1.3438 -1.4152,-1.0631 -2.1684,-2.7629 -2.25,-5.0937 5.146,-0.6811 10.2029,-2.1107 13.75,-4.8438 1.1602,-0.8949 2.6374,-2.2996 2.9063,-3.9687 0.1853,-1.1502 -0.1559,-2.1394 -0.625,-2.7188 -0.8069,-0.992 -2.194,-1.3447 -3.625,-1.4062 -1.431,-0.062 -2.9527,0.1826 -4.1875,0.5625 -2.1041,0.6446 -4.179,1.9674 -5.8125,3.5 -2.1707,2.0331 -3.4713,4.4472 -4.0938,7.4375 -2.6678,0.2184 -5.3092,0.2302 -8.0625,0.094 -0.6458,-2.8101 -1.954,-5.3461 -3.9687,-7.2813 -1.994,-1.9164 -4.7692,-3.5672 -7.8438,-4 -2.2394,-0.3138 -4.4773,-0.1393 -5.75,1.2813 -0.6121,0.683 -0.7967,1.568 -0.7187,2.375 0.078,0.807 0.4105,1.5613 0.8437,2.1875 2.9396,4.2377 9.9314,5.9986 15.8125,6.8437 -0.048,2.2531 -1.04,4.1574 -2.5312,5.2813 -1.8629,1.4025 -4.4814,1.5432 -7.1875,1.0937 -2.7062,-0.4495 -5.4571,-1.4989 -7.4688,-2.3125 -2.299,-0.9315 -4.6865,-2.0736 -7,-3.1562 -0.3863,-0.18 -0.9246,-0.3959 -1.3437,-0.5938 -0.2096,-0.099 -0.3827,-0.2007 -0.5,-0.2812 -0.1174,-0.081 -0.1274,-0.141 -0.094,-0.031 0.03,0.1 0.02,-0.1833 0.094,-0.4375 0.074,-0.2542 0.169,-0.5181 0.2187,-0.7813 0.8034,-4.2661 -1.1781,-7.5687 -3.1562,-9.5312 -2.3907,-2.3742 -5.7359,-4.14 -10.25,-4.4375 -0.5386,-0.035 -1.0585,-0.051 -1.75,0 -3.4912,0.2661 -5.9632,1.1673 -8.25,2.5625 -0.2865,0.1742 -0.7015,0.4892 -1.125,0.7812 -0.2118,0.1461 -0.3939,0.2795 -0.5625,0.375 -0.1687,0.096 -0.3336,0.1305 -0.2813,0.125 -0.096,0.01 -0.5331,-0.025 -0.9687,-0.125 -0.4357,-0.1 -0.9,-0.237 -1.3125,-0.3125 -2.28,-0.4196 -4.715,-0.7293 -7.5625,-0.4687 -5.2362,0.4806 -10.3963,3.2645 -12.5,7.1562 -0.7411,1.3696 -1.4026,3.5182 -0.9688,5.625 0.2875,1.3843 0.9875,2.2722 1.5313,3.4063 -5.3725,2.0923 -10.7498,4.0729 -16.4063,5.9375 -5.7651,1.9026 -12.076,3.2344 -19.125,3.625 -0.045,-0.012 -0.08,0.011 -0.125,0 -1.4823,-0.355 -2.8875,-0.2663 -4.0937,-0.4375 -4.0585,-0.5757 -7.3744,-1.6124 -10.3438,-3.2813 -1.9227,-1.0821 -3.7591,-2.2478 -5.1562,-3.8437 -1.3882,-1.5847 -2.641,-3.6553 -3,-5.9375 -0.8923,-5.6655 2.3522,-9.6628 5.4375,-12.2813 3.2579,-2.7687 7.6849,-4.4838 13.2812,-4.875 7.4648,-0.5246 14.7514,1.3624 18.6875,5.1563 1.7551,1.6877 3.2926,4.5095 2.7188,7.9062 -0.5147,3.0419 -2.7193,5.1202 -5.3438,6.6875 -2.7311,1.6327 -5.9595,2.2483 -9.9375,2.4375 -6.0857,0.2898 -10.7879,-1.4979 -13.3437,-4.875 -0.7959,-1.0514 -1.6786,-2.7245 -1.5,-4.2812 0.1356,-1.1738 0.8634,-2.4489 1.4687,-3.125 2.1536,-2.4001 6.9655,-4.3407 11.75,-3.5625 1.3275,0.2153 2.9683,0.8346 4.2813,1.7187 1.3129,0.8841 2.2578,2.0259 2.4062,3.3125 0.1603,1.3891 -0.4693,2.4307 -1.5937,3.1875 -1.1245,0.7569 -2.7452,1.1671 -4.375,1.0313 0.032,0 -0.2075,-0.092 -0.5,-0.1563 -0.1463,-0.032 -0.3348,-0.073 -0.5625,0.031 -0.2278,0.1044 -0.3861,0.3687 -0.4375,0.5938 l -0.125,0.4062 0.4375,0.1563 c 1.7602,0.6443 3.6904,0.441 5.2812,-0.25 1.5908,-0.6911 2.882,-1.8654 3.25,-3.3438 0.5573,-2.24 -0.501,-4.0058 -1.5937,-5.0312 -2.1059,-1.9708 -5.4955,-3.3695 -9.1563,-3.25 -5.2999,0.1711 -9.5833,2.3509 -11.25,6.0625 -0.4046,0.9016 -0.8084,1.9102 -0.7187,3.125 0.2487,3.3491 2.4305,5.3462 4.4375,6.875 2.814,2.1469 6.8933,3.4364 11.0312,3.5 4.4782,0.07 8.2323,-1.2308 11.5938,-3.0313 l 0.062,0 0.031,-0.031 c 2.1743,-1.8208 4.2938,-3.4382 5.375,-6.1875 1.2021,-3.0589 0.427,-6.6982 -1.25,-9.1875 -1.5215,-2.2622 -3.8663,-3.9193 -6.5938,-5.0312 -2.6184,-1.0647 -5.8247,-2.2577 -8.9375,-2.5313 -6.8443,-0.602 -12.6714,0.531 -17.125,3.4063 -4.0029,2.5869 -8.3547,6.7328 -8.7812,12.8125 -0.2345,3.3406 1.0534,6.2155 2.5,8.3437 1.5078,2.2193 3.7582,3.796 5.8437,5 4.6802,2.7027 10.0648,4.2606 16.6563,4.625 7.789,0.4322 14.4837,-1.3965 19.8437,-3.5312 4.6689,-1.858 9.6169,-3.9122 14.3125,-5.9063 0.3166,-0.1337 0.757,-0.3424 1.1563,-0.5 0.1996,-0.079 0.382,-0.1476 0.5312,-0.1875 0.1493,-0.04 0.2786,-0.027 0.25,-0.031 -0.037,-0.01 0.091,0.037 0.25,0.1563 0.1593,0.1195 0.3631,0.2796 0.5625,0.4687 0.3988,0.3782 0.7728,0.8251 1.125,1.0938 l 0.031,0 c 0.8054,0.6119 1.8351,1.2231 2.5313,1.625 1.6267,0.9314 3.9757,1.9196 5.9687,2.4062 4.203,1.0244 9.104,2.0081 14.75,1.6563 0.9879,-0.061 2.0492,-0.4377 2.8438,-0.3125 0.05,0.01 0.2682,0.1073 0.5,0.25 0.2318,0.1427 0.495,0.3187 0.8125,0.4687 0.5231,0.2487 1.0932,0.5069 1.625,0.7188 0.9851,0.3911 2.198,0.915 3.4062,1.1562 1.8682,0.3729 4.0893,0.458 6,0.062 1.9108,-0.3955 3.6127,-1.3378 4.0625,-3.0937 0.4024,-1.571 -0.147,-2.7576 -0.875,-3.6563 -0.6511,-0.8037 -1.3598,-1.4322 -1.8437,-2.125 0.6426,-0.6679 1.2988,-1.3427 1.875,-2.1562 0.6171,-0.8747 1.0097,-1.7608 1.5312,-2.5 2.4329,1.1007 5.0726,2.3069 7.875,3.5 2.837,1.2091 5.9629,2.5919 9.3125,2.9375 3.0499,0.3134 5.9561,-0.041 7.9063,-1.4688 l 0.062,-0.031 0.031,-0.062 c 0.6456,-0.8103 1.5399,-1.5387 2.0937,-2.75 0.4897,-1.0702 0.6518,-2.2205 0.9063,-3.4062 2.7737,0.095 5.4735,-0.031 8.0937,0.062 0.3374,3.001 1.7425,5.4253 3.7813,6.5937 2.2721,1.3023 5.0204,1.3551 7.6875,0.9063 2.667,-0.4489 5.292,-1.4182 7.375,-2.25 3.4988,-1.3976 6.6216,-3.0236 9.5,-4.3125 0.9393,1.7495 2.0222,3.3434 3.3125,4.75 -0.4049,0.5097 -0.8661,0.9588 -1.3438,1.4687 -0.5573,0.595 -1.0959,1.2782 -1.3125,2.2188 -0.09,0.3991 -0.1455,0.9165 -0.125,1.4375 0.021,0.521 0.056,1.0174 0.3125,1.4375 0.6941,1.1394 1.8065,1.8318 3.0625,2.1875 1.256,0.3557 2.6683,0.4153 4.0938,0.2812 2.8509,-0.2682 5.7594,-1.2402 7.4375,-2.0312 0.4039,-0.1903 0.7548,-0.4232 1.0625,-0.5938 0.3076,-0.1705 0.5747,-0.2733 0.6562,-0.2812 0.5341,-0.049 1.3853,0.1557 2.1875,0.2187 8.6142,0.6662 16.8912,-1.3945 22.25,-4.75 0.5182,-0.325 1.2701,-0.7181 2.0313,-1.3437 0.3437,-0.2823 0.6649,-0.6381 0.9687,-0.9375 0.1519,-0.1498 0.2964,-0.2963 0.4063,-0.375 0.1099,-0.079 0.2019,-0.096 0.1562,-0.094 -0.072,0 0.011,0.026 0.125,0.062 0.1145,0.037 0.2723,0.088 0.4375,0.1562 0.3304,0.1356 0.7159,0.3064 1.0313,0.4375 1.8069,0.7471 3.7019,1.5678 5.3125,2.1875 7.1231,2.7456 14.1303,6.5364 23.3125,7.0938 8.3487,0.5056 15.4397,-0.9787 21.1562,-4 4.2028,-2.2206 7.8629,-5.2466 9.1875,-10.2188 0.9342,-3.4983 0.1254,-6.9243 -1.3125,-9.4687 -2.3767,-4.2056 -6.1143,-7.2076 -10.7187,-9.0938 -1.9237,-0.7872 -4.1094,-1.4313 -6.6563,-1.625 z m -74.5938,5.6875 c 1.3062,-0.075 2.6305,-0.076 3.7813,0.094 2.5178,0.3683 4.6986,1.3902 6.1875,2.7813 -5.4963,1.8875 -10.1944,4.5473 -15.0625,6.9375 -2.1779,1.0702 -4.2435,2.2942 -6.5,3.125 -0.2777,-0.8708 -0.5006,-1.6345 -0.4063,-2.875 0.4462,-5.8714 5.8303,-9.7046 12,-10.0625 z m -91.875,0.3125 c 1.4339,-0.1691 3.0404,-0.028 4.3125,0.2188 4.6468,0.8997 9.0882,4.5221 9.8125,8.3125 0.2782,1.4558 0.1728,3.0967 -0.25,4.375 -1.7128,-0.5302 -3.3151,-1.5142 -5,-2.4063 -1.8698,-0.9887 -3.8286,-1.7893 -5.6875,-2.7187 -3.4861,-1.7431 -7.053,-3.5396 -11.0312,-4.8125 1.7624,-1.6949 4.6621,-2.5865 7.8437,-2.9688 z m 108.625,2.0625 c 3.3845,-0.308 6.6691,0.1012 9.4688,1.0625 -4.1544,-1.0044 -9.008,-0.8807 -13.0938,0.125 l -0.5937,0.1563 -0.094,-0.031 -0.1875,0.031 c -1.7595,0.2768 -3.3997,0.8383 -5.0313,1.375 1.2945,-0.5423 2.5206,-1.1804 3.9063,-1.625 l 0.6562,-0.1875 c 0.438,0.07 0.8569,-0.047 1.3125,-0.1563 0.4556,-0.1093 0.9223,-0.2418 1.2813,-0.3125 0.8427,-0.1667 1.7481,-0.3807 2.375,-0.4375 z m -44.8437,0.125 c 0.9094,-0.1356 1.777,-0.1019 2.5,0.125 0.6865,0.2155 1.2351,0.632 1.6562,1.3125 0,0.6606 0.015,1.3483 -0.1562,1.7188 -0.8739,1.8891 -3.0941,3.1216 -5.4688,4.3125 -1.0724,0.5391 -2.3194,1.067 -3.5312,1.4062 -1.9474,0.5452 -3.9331,0.8119 -5.9688,0.9375 0.4635,-3.5425 3.0789,-6.3307 5.9688,-7.9687 1.2249,-0.6957 3.181,-1.5725 5,-1.8438 z m -35.2188,0.1563 c 1.7812,-0.133 4.1844,0.5173 5.4688,1.0937 2.5646,1.1518 4.7704,3.0442 6.125,5.1875 0.5852,0.9293 1.0081,2.2338 1.125,3.4688 -1.4627,-0.062 -2.8587,-0.1817 -3.9375,-0.5625 l -0.031,-0.031 -0.062,0 c -2.4528,-0.2718 -4.6204,-1.2065 -6.5,-2.2188 -1.8747,-1.0111 -3.567,-2.0839 -4.5,-3.875 -0.2453,-1.1605 -0.081,-1.8471 0.3125,-2.2812 0.402,-0.4435 1.1094,-0.7148 2,-0.7813 z m -44.3125,0.125 c 1.2004,0.092 2.3487,0.2626 3.4688,0.4687 0.3475,0.063 0.8226,0.2073 1.2812,0.3125 0.4586,0.1053 0.8707,0.1984 1.2813,0.1563 0.055,-0.01 0.077,-0.051 0.125,-0.062 l -0.031,0.062 0.7187,0.2187 c 0.8224,0.2427 1.5546,0.6161 2.3438,0.9063 -1.1343,-0.3375 -2.2767,-0.6212 -3.4375,-0.75 -0.1848,-0.02 -0.38,0.049 -0.5,0.125 l 0.031,-0.1875 -0.4688,-0.094 c -3.6934,-0.7369 -7.5405,-1.0336 -11.4687,-0.5313 -0.4068,0.052 -0.7824,0.2269 -1.1875,0.3125 0.391,-0.133 0.7862,-0.2059 1.1875,-0.3125 0.9371,-0.2489 1.8825,-0.5055 2.8437,-0.5937 1.3633,-0.1248 2.6121,-0.1234 3.8125,-0.031 z m 127.5938,0.9375 c 2.2773,-0.031 4.5405,0.1978 6.5625,0.75 2.0219,0.5522 3.7886,1.4162 5.0937,2.625 1.3051,1.2088 2.1587,2.7574 2.375,4.75 0.2514,2.3144 -0.705,3.83 -1.8125,5.125 -4.7609,-1.3436 -9.6405,-2.8821 -15.2812,-3.3438 -0.3424,-0.028 -0.6564,0.01 -0.9063,0 -0.1396,0 -0.1965,-0.038 -0.2812,-0.062 0.3517,-2.2026 0.3332,-4.8607 -0.4375,-6.8125 -0.3761,-0.9475 -0.8433,-1.6168 -1.25,-2.3125 1.8836,-0.4138 3.8968,-0.6913 5.9375,-0.7187 z m -128.4688,0.5 c 1.6311,0.089 3.2174,0.3312 4.8125,0.625 -0.2105,0.4215 -0.4768,0.841 -0.8125,1.4687 -1.0426,1.9465 -1.2948,4.7992 -0.75,7.5625 -0.5337,0.1856 -0.9714,0.1641 -1.7187,0.2188 -2.4841,0.1763 -5.4129,0.7347 -7.9688,1.375 -1.0173,0.2565 -2.2836,0.5641 -3.6562,1 -0.518,0.1649 -1.1936,0.4448 -1.8438,0.6875 -0.6502,0.2426 -1.3181,0.3778 -1.4687,0.3437 0.052,0.011 -0.2431,-0.1897 -0.4688,-0.5 -0.2257,-0.3103 -0.4279,-0.6974 -0.5312,-0.9062 -1.5436,-3.1121 -0.2056,-7.0173 1.9062,-8.8438 1.5507,-1.3419 4.2569,-2.5164 6.8438,-2.8437 1.8988,-0.2429 3.8023,-0.2887 5.6562,-0.1875 z m 120.6563,0.5312 c 0.9315,0.7135 1.6893,2.0161 2.0625,3.625 0.3656,1.5764 0.3663,3.403 -0.031,5.0625 -8.7123,0.1463 -16.3797,1.8778 -22,5.4688 -1.4594,-1.0416 -2.5114,-2.5033 -3.2188,-4.3438 3.5133,-1.9133 7.0271,-3.8655 10.75,-5.5 3.9322,-1.7249 7.9928,-3.5676 12.4375,-4.3125 z m -114.0938,0.375 c 2.1288,0.2477 4.3606,1.0299 6.5,1.75 5.8877,1.9857 11.753,5.2079 16.8438,7.8438 -0.5848,1.8915 -1.7074,3.2482 -3.0625,4.4687 -5.6932,-3.4677 -12.9573,-5.3333 -22.0625,-5.3125 -0.4823,-1.4613 -0.5294,-3.2374 -0.1875,-4.8437 0.3647,-1.7134 1.1187,-3.212 1.9687,-3.9063 z m 113.1563,9.8125 c 0.8657,-0.041 1.7032,-0.048 2.4062,0.094 -0.197,0.7704 -0.4764,1.6265 -0.875,2.25 -0.9276,1.4493 -2.4975,2.9386 -4.0625,4.0938 -0.7068,0.5189 -1.4859,1.0751 -2.4375,1.625 -0.4273,0.2479 -0.9587,0.5945 -1.4375,0.875 -0.4788,0.2805 -0.929,0.4799 -1.0937,0.5 l -0.031,0 c -0.3281,0.041 -0.8488,-0.055 -1.4063,-0.2188 -0.5574,-0.1634 -1.1262,-0.3584 -1.625,-0.5 -2.8289,-0.8103 -5.2058,-2.0985 -7.1875,-3.6562 0.7748,-0.755 1.9024,-1.3169 3.0938,-1.8438 3.997,-1.7703 9.0371,-2.9573 14.6562,-3.2187 z m 4.0625,0.1875 c 0.011,3e-4 0.02,-2e-4 0.031,0 6.0603,0.1364 10.8834,1.4948 15.5312,3.0938 -0.9087,1.0867 -2.2169,1.9264 -3.6875,2.75 -4.8235,2.6977 -12.7966,4.4619 -20.0625,3.7187 0.5811,-0.4342 1.1704,-0.8596 1.75,-1.3125 2.6541,-2.0741 5.1157,-4.6456 6.4375,-8.25 z m -118.5625,0.1563 c 0.086,0.01 0.1055,0.048 0.25,0.031 2.108,-0.2528 4.3751,-0.03 6.4687,0.2187 4.0152,0.477 8.1502,1.7048 11.2813,3.2188 0.9143,0.4425 1.7624,0.8872 2.3125,1.4375 -1.9769,1.5646 -4.3123,2.8769 -7.2188,3.75 -0.4633,0.14 -1.0409,0.3708 -1.5937,0.5312 -0.5528,0.1605 -1.0972,0.2485 -1.4063,0.2188 -0.2528,-0.024 -0.7273,-0.2206 -1.2187,-0.5 -0.4915,-0.2794 -1.0189,-0.6237 -1.4688,-0.875 -2.7136,-1.5109 -4.8218,-3.5178 -6.5625,-5.9063 -0.1842,-0.4435 -0.4413,-0.8604 -0.625,-1.2187 -0.1671,-0.326 -0.2076,-0.6068 -0.2187,-0.9063 z m -1.6875,0.094 c 0.021,-7e-4 0.01,0.01 0.031,0.031 0.026,0.025 0.07,0.096 0.125,0.2187 0.1097,0.2454 0.2187,0.6138 0.375,0.9688 1.6765,3.7979 4.871,6.1318 7.8437,8.4062 -2.6338,0.3312 -5.5484,0.3272 -8.1562,0 -6.3727,-0.8014 -12.1822,-2.9292 -15.75,-6.25 0.6934,-0.3381 1.438,-0.5913 2.3437,-0.875 3.887,-1.2157 8.2991,-2.351 13.1875,-2.5 z m 164.8437,2.5937 c 0.8134,0.2778 1.6042,0.5542 2.5,0.75 -0.6108,-0.1835 -1.289,-0.2226 -1.875,-0.4375 -0.2355,-0.087 -0.3971,-0.2221 -0.625,-0.3125 z m 4.2188,1.1875 c 1.963,0.2898 4.0417,0.3424 6.125,0.2188 -1.423,0.1906 -2.9389,0.2507 -4.5,0.1562 -0.5862,-0.035 -1.0695,-0.2679 -1.625,-0.375 z m -215.8125,0.2813 c -1.8358,0.5133 -3.7976,0.8145 -5.9375,0.7812 -0.4929,-0.01 -0.9476,-0.2055 -1.4375,-0.25 0.7581,0.031 1.4818,0.1318 2.2812,0.094 1.8458,-0.088 3.5033,-0.2925 5.0938,-0.625 z m 143.7187,1.5312 c 1.4041,0.9492 2.9827,1.9265 4.75,2.7188 0.9131,0.4064 1.8005,0.8012 2.7813,1.125 0.5774,0.192 1.0867,0.4156 1.625,0.5937 -1.587,0.7649 -3.5558,1.4942 -5.6563,1.8438 -1.5056,0.2523 -3.2714,0.1853 -4.4687,-0.3438 -0.5987,-0.2645 -1.0549,-0.6414 -1.3125,-1.0937 -0.2577,-0.4523 -0.3422,-1.0262 -0.1563,-1.8125 0.2914,-1.2322 1.3915,-2.0547 2.4375,-3.0313 z m -73.7187,0.2188 c 0.1789,0.015 0.3803,0.1009 0.625,0.3437 0.2686,0.2666 0.5377,0.6174 0.8125,0.9375 0.3384,0.3928 0.8009,1.0331 1.0625,1.6875 0.2615,0.6545 0.3216,1.2856 -0.062,1.9063 -0.6831,1.1028 -2.2356,1.5237 -4.0938,1.5 -1.8582,-0.024 -3.9337,-0.5038 -5.3125,-0.9688 -0.7718,-0.2599 -1.4005,-0.6077 -2.0625,-0.9375 0.5286,-0.2043 1.05,-0.4014 1.625,-0.5937 2.7332,-0.9114 5.3166,-2.2019 7.4063,-3.875 z m -51.375,1.375 c -1.9341,0.7944 -3.8745,1.6286 -5.75,2.375 -5.1636,2.0565 -11.5418,3.791 -18.9375,3.4687 6.6433,-0.4739 12.7174,-1.6844 18.2187,-3.5 2.2332,-0.7361 4.3042,-1.5749 6.4688,-2.3437 z m 177.75,0.031 c 3.7066,1.2766 7.6958,2.6442 11.4687,3.5312 3.9354,0.925 8.5857,1.5947 13.1563,1.5625 -2.0046,0.1367 -4.0905,0.1639 -6.2813,0.031 -7.0191,-0.426 -12.7113,-2.7834 -18.3437,-5.125 z m -39.0313,1.9688 c -0.066,0.05 -0.1219,0.106 -0.1875,0.1563 l -0.5,0.375 c -0.1121,-3e-4 -0.201,-0.042 -0.3125,-0.031 0.2353,-0.1112 0.476,-0.1703 0.7188,-0.3125 0.1045,-0.061 0.1776,-0.1243 0.2812,-0.1875 z m -100.75,0.3438 c 0.079,0.047 0.1384,0.079 0.2188,0.125 0.2852,0.1621 0.5849,0.2262 0.875,0.3437 -0.1673,-0.025 -0.2721,0.034 -0.4375,0.031 l -0.5,-0.375 c -0.052,-0.041 -0.1039,-0.084 -0.1563,-0.125 z m 98.625,0.4375 c 0.1043,-7e-4 0.2093,0.044 0.3125,0.031 -0.071,0.038 -0.1469,0.054 -0.2187,0.094 -0.3346,0.1854 -0.6923,0.4028 -1.0313,0.5625 -0.4687,0.2209 -1.2138,0.4525 -1.875,0.6875 0.7152,-0.308 1.4665,-0.6231 2.0313,-0.9375 l 0.7812,-0.4375 z m -96.4687,0.2812 0.031,0 0.6562,0.4375 c 0.7149,0.4567 1.5962,0.7912 2.4688,1.125 -0.3449,-0.1344 -0.7127,-0.2173 -1.0313,-0.3437 -0.5222,-0.2081 -1.0716,-0.4542 -1.5625,-0.6875 -0.2265,-0.107 -0.4653,-0.2502 -0.7187,-0.4063 -0.045,-0.028 -0.1112,-0.035 -0.1563,-0.062 0.1015,0.01 0.2092,-0.061 0.3125,-0.062 z m 4.5937,2.0625 c 0.7614,0.2316 1.7211,0.3119 2.6563,0.4688 -0.6459,-0.051 -1.2853,-0.1011 -1.875,-0.2188 -0.2526,-0.05 -0.5182,-0.1717 -0.7813,-0.25 z"
     style="fill: #000000" />
```

I know that positioning values are embedded in the **d** attribute. But i don't understand how i can modify these value according to my use. Can anyone please guide me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The shape is dependent on the `d` attribute, but the placement can be modified using `translate` in the `transform` attribute.

```
transform="translate(x, y)"
```

Comment: Sure thing, does this answer your question?